# View plist data in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, plist

The thing is. i want to display the each object to the tableview not it's under subs so in this case. 123.
i can't seem to figured out how to display the that one item...
also. the way it saves the plist now it overwrites the plist it seems. since it's fresh created each time i go add 
i followed numbers torturials on the web and here on stack overflow. but none seem to get close to what i want to do.

[image: plist]

MainTableViewController.h

```
{
NSMutableDictionary *arrayD;
}
```

MainTableViewController.m

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


// Property List.plist code
//Gets paths from root direcory.
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//Get documents path.
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//Get the path to our PList file.
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Servers.plist"];

//Check to see if Property List.plist exists in documents.
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]){
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Servers" ofType:@"plist"] toPath:plistPath error:nil];
    //If not in documents, get property list from main bundle.
//        plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Servers" ofType:@"plist"];

}

//Read property list into memory as an NSData object.
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];

NSString *errorDesc = nil;

NSPropertyListFormat format;

//convert static property list into dictionary object.
NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];

    if (!temp){
        NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
            }

    //Display values.
NSMutableDictionary *dictinoary =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

tableData = [dictinoary objectForKey:@"Hostname"];
NSLog(@"Count: %i", [arrayD count]);
```

}

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Hostname";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

}

cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
```

}

AddServerViewController.m

```
    - (IBAction)SaveData:(id)sender {
//Get paths from root direcory.
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//Get documents path.
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

//Get the path to our PList file.
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Servers.plist"];

//Set the variables to the values in the text fields.
hostName = hostEntered.text;
portNumber = portEntered.text;
userName = userNameEntered.text;
passWord = passWordEntered.text;

NSMutableDictionary *rootObj = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:4];
NSMutableDictionary *data;
data = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: hostName, portNumber, userName, passWord, nil]                                      forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hostname", @"Port", @"Username", @"Password", nil]];
[rootObj setObject:data forKey:hostName];


NSString *error = nil;

//Create NSData from dictionary.
NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:rootObj format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&error];

//Check is plistData exists.
if(plistData){

    //Write plistData to our Properity List.plist file.
    [plistData writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

}
else{
    NSLog(@"Error in saveData: %@", error);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each dictionary has allKeys method that returns an array with... all keys.
If you do what Peter said and then you can just populate your tableView with allKeys

Comment: i dont quiete understand this allKeys. could you make a example ?

Comment: figured it out.. how ever when i do tableData = [dictinoary allKeys]; it says : incompatible pointer types assigning to NSMutableArray from Nsarray. how to fix this then ?

Comment: `NSArray *myArray = [yourDictionary allKeys];` then you can use myArray to populate all the keys in your tableview. I'm not sure though if this is what you need

Comment: `tabledata = [[dictionary allKeys] copy];` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I misread your question but the following was done after recreating your plist:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sample List" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *plistDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

NSLog(@"Plist dict %@", [plistDict objectForKey:@"123"]);
```

That would output:

```
Plist dict {
    Hostname = 123;
    Password = 123;
    Port = 123;
    Username = 123;
}
```

Is that what you were looking for? If not, ill need a bit more detail with regards to what it is that you're looking for.

Comment: i want to view the hostname in my uitableview and only hostname.. but if it worked properly it would have a few more entries and then it would be hostname for each entries in the plist

Comment: Based on the example above you would simply do `[[plistDict objectForKey:@"123"] objectForKey:@"Hostname"]`

Comment: that works. but what if it was called something else ? then i would need to change the code each time. aint there a smarter way ? say there is 2 entries one with 123 and 456 so with out change the code but make it generic so it would show hostname of those two. is that possible or do i need to change the code ?

Comment: If the plist is a different name? What you're getting back is a dictionary. Simply loop through the keys until you find what you're looking for.

Comment: no plist's name stays the same. simple just adding more entries

Comment: Then you'd use objectForKey and pass it whatever you want.